# A ClickableSpan on a String not text

Tags: java, android, string, indexoutofboundsexception, clickablespan

Ok I have a ClickableSpan (on a TextView called SpecialTextView) that is working perfectly, it contains a String of text (called specialtappedtext).  When another ClickableSpan on a different TextView (called BottomTextView) is longclicked it addsthe clicked word to SpecialTextView like this -

```
specialtappedtext = BottomTextView.getText().toString().substring(startSelection, endSelection);
SpecialTextView.append(" " + specialtappedtext);
```

The result is SpecialTextView displays whatever words the user taps.  All good so far, but I'm then allowing the user to longclick a word in SpecialTextView to then remove it.  I get a String (called wordtobedeleted) from what the user taps on in SpecialTextView and then a String (called fullspecialtext) which is the full line of text as it appears in SpecialTextView.  I then replace any instance of wordtobedeleted that appears in fullspecialtext and display the result back in SpecialTextView like this -

```
wordtobedeleted = SpecialTextView.getText().toString().substring(startSelection, endSelection);
resultspecialtext = fullspecialtext.replace(wordtobedeleted, " ");
SpecialTextView.setText(" " + resultspecialtext);
```

So if the user taps the words "Bandit is in the living room" as displayed in BottomTextView then SpecialTextView will display them in that order tapped.  Pressing any of these words in the SpecialTextView should remove them, so if I tap the words "is", "the" and "living" the SpecialTextView will display "Bandit in room" but instead I get a crash.  It's seems that I can't get a substring from a textview that contains a string, if I'm reading this right as when I comment out code the part that causes the crash is where I get the String wordtobedeleted from SpecialTextView.

The ClickableSpan, sorry about some of the long winded names it helps me to at a glance keep track of what's what because I'm juggling another ClickableSpan with almost identical names etc.  -

```
 SpecialTextView.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
 SpecialTextView.setText(specialtappedtext, TextView.BufferType.SPANNABLE);
 Spannable specialspans = (Spannable) SpecialTextView.getText();
 BreakIterator specialiterator = BreakIterator.getWordInstance(Locale.UK);
 specialiterator.setText(specialtappedtext);
 int specialstart = specialiterator.first();
 for (int specialend = specialiterator.next(); specialend != BreakIterator.DONE; specialstart = specialend, specialend = specialiterator
            .next()) {
     String specpossibleWord = specialtappedtext.substring(specialstart, specialend);
     if (Character.isLetterOrDigit(specpossibleWord.charAt(0))) {
            ClickableSpan specialclickSpan = getSpecialClickableSpan(specpossibleWord);
         specialspans.setSpan(specialclickSpan, specialstart, specialend,
                    Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
     }
 }
```

Whether it helps or not, but here's the error log thing -

```
 Process: com.example.warrenanna.game003, PID: 18321
                                                                            java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=30; index=-1
                                                                                at java.lang.String.substring(String.java:1926)
                                                                                at com.example.warrenanna.game003.MainActivity$2.onLongClick(MainActivity.java:133)
                                                                                at android.view.View.performLongClickInternal(View.java:5762)
                                                                                at android.view.View.performLongClick(View.java:5720)
                                                                                at android.widget.TextView.performLongClick(TextView.java:9427)
                                                                                at android.view.View.performLongClick(View.java:5738)
                                                                                at android.view.View$CheckForLongPress.run(View.java:22450)
                                                                                at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
                                                                                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:241)
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6281)
                                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
```

I'm new to anything this advanced in programming and I don't really know my way around ClickableSpan so I'm kind of winging it but was doing fine until now!

Comment: Actually according to your code, you will get "Bandit[space][space][space]in the room" with three spaces because you're calling `replace` with a space; are you sure you're not miscounting the index with that extra space?

Comment: Thanks for your reply, you're right about the spaces, but I've not got to the point where that part of the code actually takes place - but I can live with spaces if "" doesn't work.  The way the code works is I never specify exactly the index, the code in theory calculates that depending on where the selection of a word starts and ends.  But I think indexing is where the problem lies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> you problem is
>
> `java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=30; index=-1`

- Check `wordtobedeleted = SpecialTextView.getText().toString().substring(startSelection, endSelection);` in your code .

`startSelection` and `endSelection` are possible  equal to -1 .

- Check `String specpossibleWord = specialtappedtext.substring(specialstart, specialend);` in your code .

`specialstart` and `specialend` are possible equal to -1.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I'm not sure how the index can = -1 when the code should calculate that all for me based on where text selection starts and ends.  I wonder if I can use startSelection+1 and endSelection+1 etc etc to get what I'm after.

Comment: You can add log in your code .Show the `substring` index .

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, that's a little beyond me at the moment so I'll look into how to get a log of the substring index.  I just don't understand why it's not working when I've copy and pasted it from my first one that works perfectly.

Comment: Good luck to you .